# Python: what does a comprehension in a set() mean?

Tags: python

I saw something like:

```
set(x for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

I know `x for x in [1, 2, 3]` is a comprehension, but I cannot find a valid grammar for it, since `x for x in [1, 2, 3]` itself is invalid.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [python3 reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls)

```
call ::=  primary "(" [argument_list [","] | comprehension] ")"
comprehension ::=  expression comp_for
```

check:

```
set(x for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

`set` is `primary`, `x` is `expression` and `for x in [1, 2, 3]` is `comp_for`

Answer (score 4):

It is to create a set based on the comprehension. Example:

```
a = set(x for x in [1, 2, 3])
print(a)
```

The result will be a set:

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

In the above example, it happen to be the logic can be simplified to:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])
```

Where you do not need a comprehension at all

Answer (score 4):

It's a *generator expression*. They are normally surrounded by parens, but the parens can be omitted if the expression is the only argument to a function call:

```
>>> generator = (x for x in [1, 2, 3])
>>> generator.next()
1
>>> set(generator)
set([2, 3])
```

Generator objects can be iterated over, they produce values one by one. Compared to using a list comprehension here, the advantage is that no intermediate list object has to be created (which matters more if there are, say, a million elements rather than three).

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Comment: Thanks for actually explaining *why* the parentheses from the generator expression can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

python's set based on comprehension. example for list with strings

```
>>> address = set(city for city in ["Paris", "Paris", "London","Berlin","Paris","Paris"])

>>> print address
set(['Paris', 'Berlin', 'London'])

>>> type(address)
<type 'set'>
```

Answer (score 1):

`(x for x in [1, 2, 3])` is a [Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

It reduces an iterable input to a single value.

```
>>> (x for x in [1, 2, 3])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1b23bea8c0>
>>> type(x for x in [1,2,3])
<type 'generator'>
```

It match with the constructor of the `set` class.

```
def __init__(self, seq=()): # known special case of set.__init__
        """
        set() -> new empty set object
        set(iterable) -> new set object

        Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
        # (copied from class doc)
        """
```

There are in **Python 3** a set comprehension like that:

```
{x for x in [1, 2, 3]}
```

So you don't need `set(x for x in [1, 2, 3])` anymore in **Python 3**.